# What does the "over that of" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I'm not a native English speaker, so I had a trouble when translating the follow sentence:

> The use of an implicit operator of this form liberalizes the stability restrictions appreciably and raises the maximal permissible value of min by a factor of 2-10 **over that of** an explicit scheme of time advancement at typical values of the problem and grid parameters used in the simulations.

What does the **over that of** mean?? Could you comment please?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Please note: we are no translation service, but we *will* answer specific questions. So, please add your own thoughts - what *did* you understand?

Comment: Yeaap, I see!But I didn't ask you to translate all the text.I just wanted smb to explain me the meaning of the word combination. That's it!

Answer (score 1):

The "over that of" is a comparison that could be replaced with "**more than**" or "**better than**".  Even as native English speaker, I had to read this sentence multiple times to understand it because of how long it is.  Stripping out technical details, I've reduced the sentence to get a much easier sentence to parse.

> "[This technique] raises [something] by a factor of 2 to 10 times more than [something else]"

Comment: Thank you a lot =). It's a part of mathematical article and I have to interpret every single sentence to realise it.